# Exportar mas de una sentencia de SQL a Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Buenas estoy implementando una tarea en sql server para exportar 3 sentencias a un excel
pero cuando abro el excel solo me trae la primera consulta,
que mas le podria agregar para que me aparesca una respuesta debajo de otra

aqui esta la query la cual se ejecuta y da 3 respuestas

```
/*
son iguales a la lista
*/
SELECT  *
    FROM prueba T1
    INNER JOIN pruebaExcel T2
        ON  T1.pin = T2.pin
    WHERE   ISNULL(T1.fecha,'NULL') = ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, T2.[Date], 103),'NULL')
        AND ISNULL(T1.importe_pago,-1) = ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(12), CAST(T2.[Order Amt] AS decimal(20,0))),-1)
        AND ISNULL(T1.Comision,-1) = ISNULL(T2.[Commission Amt],-1)
/*
diferencia entre 
*/
SELECT  t1.fecha,t1.ubicacion,t1.articulo,t1.beneficiario,t1.pin,t1.seq,
t1.tipo_moneda,t1.importe_pago,t2.[Order Amt] 'Diferencia de Pago',t1.importe_pago_usd,t1.comision,t1.comision_dolares
    FROM prueba T1
    INNER JOIN pruebaExcel T2
        ON  T1.pin = T2.pin
    WHERE ISNULL(T1.importe_pago,-1) != ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(12), CAST(T2.[Order Amt] AS decimal(20,0))),-1)  
/*
no estan en la lista
*/   

   SELECT  T2.*
    FROM prueba T1
    INNER JOIN pruebaExcel T2
        ON  T1.pin != T2.pin
```

y solo me guarda la primera consulta y no las demas una debajo de otra. gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál método estás usando para exportar?

Comment: Hola, ahora lo hize manualmente, haciendo click derecho en la base de datos y en task

Comment: Has probado con [Azure Data Studio. Exportar a excel a un botón](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2021/02/08/exportar-consultas-a-excel-por-fin-es-tan-facil-como-pulsar-un-boton/). Tampoco esta clara la salida que esperas. Puede ser que dado que utilizas las mismas tablas, puedas montar la query como un `UNION ALL` de los tres conjuntos. Y meter por el medio un separador. Pero sería necesario que completes tú pregunta. Que tienes, y que esperas obtener.

Comment: Mediante VBA podrías crear una macro que ejecute cada consulta de 1 en 1 y te devuelva cada conjunto de datos en un rango u hoja diferente, según tus necesidades. Solo desde SQL puro no vas a poder salvo que te construyas una UNION ALL y sea todo en una única petición.